# Passing a query as a parameter in stored proc

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored proc that takes in `nvarchar` but it is going to part of the query as shown below:

```
Input Parameter @InputQuery =  '21 OR RevenueAccrualID =  22'
```

I want to add the input query to my existing query:

```
UPDATE [RevenueAccrual] SET Posted=1
 Where [RevenueAccrual].RevenueAccrualID = @InputQueryPart
```

The output I want is to be as:

```
UPDATE [RevenueAccrual] SET Posted=1
Where [RevenueAccrual].RevenueAccrualID = 21
OR RevenueAccrualID =  22
```

What it does at the moment is:

```
 UPDATE [RevenueAccrual] SET Posted=1
 Where [RevenueAccrual].RevenueAccrualID = '21 OR RevenueAccrualID =  22'
```

I want to know if there is a way to pass a query as a parameter and use it in SQL Server. The input query will differ depending on the situation.

Comment: In your sproc, you need to create your sql as a string, then concatenate your restriction on to the end and `exec` the string.  Or use an `IN`

Comment: use an `IN` clause if you are not sure about the number of parameters. Something like `Where [RevenueAccrual].RevenueAccrualID IN (21,22)`

Comment: Beware of [little booby tables.](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to encapsulate the entire query in the string - so if you're passing @InputQuery into a stored procedure, then it should look something like this:

```
DECLARE @QueryString NVARCHAR(500)

SET @QueryString = 'UPDATE [RevenueAccrual] SET Posted=1 Where [RevenueAccrual].RevenueAccrualID = '
SET @QueryString = @QueryString + @InputQuery
EXEC (@QueryString)
```

So it can execute the entire thing at once. However, I'd probably change that approach if its always going to be integer values in the same field using IN

```
DECLARE @InputQuery NVARCHAR(30)
SET @InputQuery = '21, 22'
EXEC RunThisThang(@InputQuery)
```

Then your stored procedure looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE RunThisThang (@InputStr)
AS

DECLARE @QUeryStr NVARCHAR(500)

SET @QueryStr = 'UPDATE [RevenueAccrual] SET Posted=1 Where [RevenueAccrual].RevenueAccrualID IN (' + @InputStr + ')'
EXEC (@QueryStr)
```

Comment: After creating the Stored Procedure, did you run something like EXEC RunThisThang('21,22')?

Comment: While this answers the question, I highly recommend to not use this approach. Dynamic sql queries are prone to sql injection attacks and should be avoided if possible.

Comment: Agree completely with Zohar - this is not ideal and should be considered a hacktical solution until something better (more permanent) can be done. This query isn't so dangerous, but it can lead to the dark side: throwing whole query strings around!

Answer (score 1):

Why you are passing the query as a parameter. This is very bad way of programming. Just pass the variables and write query is sp.

Passing query to sp is not an optimized way.

Comment: We are using a software that has limitations so we have to do these "hacks" to make it work