# How to pass query into store procedure as a parameter in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I want to pass the query into the stored procedure as a parameter and execute the stored procedure.
I want to do like this one,

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE function1(query1, query2, query3)
BEGIN
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION,SQLWARNING
  rollback;

  start transaction;
    // I want to execute query 1 here
    // I want to execute query 2 here
    // I want to execute query 3 here
  commit;
END
```

Please help me here how can I pass the whole queries into the stored procedure as a parameter and execute parallel.

Thank you in advance

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here ? Stored procedures are supposed to contain queries - not pass into them as a parameter !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a query as a parameter in stored proc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30226688/passing-a-query-as-a-parameter-in-stored-proc)

Comment: You'd have to pass them as strings and then [`PREPARE` and `EXECUTE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) them. But be aware, that this can be easily abused, if somebody passes malicious statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE to run the queries. EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'QUERY1'; will execute QUERY1. As pointed out by @sticky bit beware of malicious statements.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm